# If $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$ and $p = k$, then $\sigma(p^k)/2$ is not squarefree.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers, conjectures, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

While researching the topic of [odd perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers), we came across the following implication, which we currently do not know how to prove:

> **CONJECTURE:** If $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$ and $p = k$, then $\sigma(p^k)/2$ is not [squarefree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer).

Here, $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$ is the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$.  (Note that both $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$ hold.)

**OUR ATTEMPT**

Here are the details of our search in the range $5 \leq p < 50$, $1 \leq k < 50$ using the following Sage Math Cell - Pari-GP scripts:

> [**(1)** Searching for examples where $\sigma(p^k)/2$ is **not squarefree**](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxVTcsKwjAQ_JWxh7ILC7aix3yCvyCENltyqNWkQvL3LmIpncswwzx0SVRcL7h1AjVRNxGVKOZXinOgwoy2Bd2XkYpcGc6h3616sE5Wy--PT0FTCJTjNHsqj8rnC7PY4HO1kQZAI_XP6ofVzvfsD1_9XirS&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

```
for(x=1, 50, for(y=1, 50, if((isprime(x)) && (Mod(x,4) == 1) && (Mod(y,4) == 1) && !(issquarefree(sigma(x^y)/2)),print(x,"   ",y,"   ",factor(sigma(x^y))))))
```

> Output:
> [image: First Sage Math Cell Output]

> [**(2)** Searching for examples where $\sigma(p^k)/2$ is **squarefree**](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLyy_SqLA11FEwNdBRSANyKmGczDQNjczigqLM3FSNCk1NBTU1BQ3f_BSNCh0TTQVbWwVDhFAlqlBmcXFhaWJRalpRaqpGcWZ6bqJGRVylpr6RpqYO0Ly8EqAZSgoKCko6lVA6LTG5BGg3Qi0YAADfdSqx&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

```
for(x=1, 50, for(y=1, 50, if((isprime(x)) && (Mod(x,4) == 1) && (Mod(y,4) == 1) && (issquarefree(sigma(x^y)/2)),print(x,"   ",y,"   ",factor(sigma(x^y))))))
```

> Output:
> [image: Second Sage Math Cell Output]

---

As you can see, the **Conjecture** does appear plausible.  However, computational searches are **very far** from a complete proof, though they certainly add to the evidence supporting the **Conjecture**.

---

Here is our:

**QUESTION:** Does anybody here have any ideas on how to prove the **Conjecture**?

Comment: Nice project, but I do not understand how the examples (both the squarefree ones and the non-squarefree ones) help us to prove the conjecture. And what is meant with "the conjecture is plausible" ? How does the data support the conjecture ?

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, @Peter.  If you (barely) noticed in the outputs, it does appear that the implication $p = k$ implies that $\sigma(p^k)/2$ is **not squarefree** holds, in the sense that I **did not get an instance** of when "the hypothesis $p = k$ is true but the conclusion $\sigma(p^k)/2$ is **not squarefree** does not hold".  (By the contrapositive, $\sigma(p^k)/2$ is squarefree would conjecturally imply that $p \neq k$, which is what the data **indeed** shows.)

Comment: One can *click* on the image to get a better view, @Peter.  And yes, quite indeed, we do not need a double loop over $k$ and $p$, since it would simply be $\sigma(p^p)/2$ which has to be checked.

Comment: Though we differentiated between $p$ and $k$ in order to double-check that, indeed, $\sigma(p^k)/2$ **is squarefree** would imply that $p \neq k$, @Peter.  (I mean, they are two sides of the same coin.)

Comment: @Peter: The updated Pari-GP scripts

*for(x=1, 10000, if((isprime(x)) && (Mod(x,4) == 1) && !(issquarefree(sigma(x^x)/2)),print(x)))*

and

*for(x=1, 10000, if((isprime(x)) && (Mod(x,4) == 1) && (issquarefree(sigma(x^x)/2)),print(x)))*

are working flawlessly and as designed, with the second script returning $0$ rows.  This gives further computational evidence in support of the **Conjecture**.

Comment: @Peter: The case of $p$ being a Mersenne prime is ruled out by the requirement that the special prime ought to satisfy $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, since if $2^n - 1$ is prime, then $2 \leq n$ is prime.  (Note that $2^n - 1 \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ for $n \geq 2$.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142048/discussion-between-peter-and-jose-arnaldo-bebita-dris).

Comment: @Peter: The fact that $q \mid (p + 1)$ is guaranteed by the fact that $(p + 1)/2$ is odd.  Can you check if putting $q = (p + 1)/2$ proves the **Conjecture**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prove the slight stronger conjecture :

> Let $p$ be an odd prime , not being a Mersenne prime and $q$ be the smallest odd prime factor of $p+1$. Then, we have $q^2\mid p^{p+1}-1$ from which we can conclude that $\frac{\sigma(p^p)}{2}$ is not squarefree.

Proof : With $s:=p+1$ we have $$p^{p+1}-1=(s-1)^{p+1}-1\equiv (-1)^p\cdot s(p+1)+(-1)^{p+1}-1=(-1)^p\cdot (s(p+1)-1)-1=-s(p+1)=-s^2\equiv 0 \mod s^2$$ So , we have $(p+1)^2\mid p^{p+1}-1$.Because of $q\mid p+1$ , this finishes the proof.

Comment: If $p$ is of the form $4k+3$ (covering the Mersenne prime case) , then $p-1$ is not divisible by $4$ , but $p^{p+1}-1$ is divisible by $16$. Hence $\frac{\sigma(p^p)}{2}$ is divisible by $4$ in this case, hence again not squarefree.